# Android StreetView check if there is any view for given location

Tags: android, google-street-view

I'm just playing around with the new StreetView feature of the Google Play Services 4.4 for Android ([link](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/StreetViewPanoramaView.html)) and I was wondering if there is any method /possibility to check if there is a 'view'/ foto material for any given location. 
When I load a location that isn't covered by StreetView with `streetViewPanorama.setPosition(someLatLng);` 
I just get a black screen. 
Any way to check beforehand?

Answer (score 13):

Black screen appears when location is not present. Just check whether it was loaded or not.

```
@Override
public void onStreetViewPanoramaReady(StreetViewPanorama streetViewPanorama) {
    mPanorama.setOnStreetViewPanoramaChangeListener(new StreetViewPanorama.OnStreetViewPanoramaChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onStreetViewPanoramaChange(StreetViewPanoramaLocation streetViewPanoramaLocation) {
            if (streetViewPanoramaLocation != null && streetViewPanoramaLocation.links != null) {
                // location is present
            } else {
                // location not available
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Yes, you are right, it was my mistake, so deleting my comments.

Answer (score 8):

```
@Override
public void onStreetViewPanoramaReady(StreetViewPanorama streetViewPanorama) {
mPanorama.setOnStreetViewPanoramaChangeListener(new StreetViewPanorama.OnStreetViewPanoramaChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onStreetViewPanoramaChange(StreetViewPanoramaLocation streetViewPanoramaLocation) {
        if (streetViewPanoramaLocation != null && streetViewPanoramaLocation.links != null) {
            // location is present
        } else {
            // location not available
        }
    }
});
```

<s>looking at the documentation I believe this should do it</s>

```
StreetViewPanoramaLocation location = mSvp.getLocation();
if (location != null && location.links != null) {
    mSvp.setPosition(location.links[0].panoId);
}
```

it is my understanding that if `location` is null or `location.links` (links is the array of street view images) is null then it is safe to say there is no street view at that position

referencing from this link

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/streetview

**Edit**

testing this out there is a caveat to this method, you have to wait until the view has been created. so for example doing this inside the fragment itself in the `onCreateView` I put in a handler with a 1 second delay to test out this theory.

```
Handler h = new Handler();
h.postDelayed(new Runnable(){

    @Override
    public void run() {
        StreetViewPanoramaLocation svpl = mSvp.getLocation();

        if(svpl == null){
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Unable to show Street View at this location", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

}, 1000);
```

if you try to use the `getLocation()` before the view has been created it will always return null. Accessing it after will return null if there is no street view at those coordinates

**Edit 2:**

there is now a callback that you should use to let you know when the streetview is ready

```
getStreetViewPanoramaAsync(new OnStreetViewPanoramaReadyCallback(){
    @Override
    public void onStreetViewPanoramaReady(StreetViewPanorama streetViewPanorama) {

    }
})
```

https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/StreetViewPanoramaView.html#getStreetViewPanoramaAsync(com.google.android.gms.maps.OnStreetViewPanoramaReadyCallback)