# StreetViewPanorama gestures crash

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, google-street-view

I'm trying to create an android widget based on a ViewSwitcher with a MapView and StreetViewPanoramaView inside. Users can switch from street to map view with a overlayed control bar.

So far all is working fine for the map part, but not for the street view part.

On first display it seems to work but when i tried to move inside (pan and/or zoom) StreetViewPanorama crash (become black).

this is how i create my StreetViewPanorama :

```
final StreetViewPanoramaOptions options = new StreetViewPanoramaOptions();
    options.streetNamesEnabled(true)
            .zoomGesturesEnabled(true)
            .panningGesturesEnabled(true);

    mStreetView = new StreetViewPanoramaView(getActivity(), options);
    mStreetView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
```

And how I defiened the location for both (map and street view)

```
 // Set map to position and add a new marker
    final GoogleMap map = mMapView.getMap();
    map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(mLocation, DEFAULT_ZOOM_LEVEL));
    if (mMarker != null){
        mMarker.remove();
    }
    mMarker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().draggable(false).position(mLocation));

    // Set street view to location.
    final StreetViewPanorama street = mStreetView.getStreetViewPanorama();
    street.setPosition(mLocation, 50);

    // Hide by default controls and street view button.
    // I will be enabled only if it's a valid street view location
    mControlsView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    mStreetBtnContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    switchToMapView();

    // we must add a delay to check if the new street view location is valid.
    // see : http://stackoverflow.com/a/23785186
    mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mHasStreetView = street.getLocation() != null;
            if (mHasStreetView){
                mStreetBtnContainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            showControlView();
        }
    }, STREET_DELAY_MILLIS);
```

Did someone encounter the same problem ?

Cheers.

Comment: I've solved my problem by removing animation on the StreetViewPanoramaView from the previous code. On the contrary of MapView i think that StreetPanoramaView doesn't support animations.

Comment: and finally... I've find out a proper solution for using animation on StreetViewPanoramaView. My mistake was defining a position on a gone view. By setting visibility to INVISIBLE **before** setting street position the strange view behaviours disappeared.

Comment: I also face the same issue. Street view crash and screen goes black on pan gesture. By making street view and map view invisible instead of gone fixed the issue.