# StreetViewPanorama.getLocation always return null.

Tags: android, android-maps-v2, android-location

I am Using StreetViewPanorama View in my Activity.

Initially I set the position for StreetViewPanorama using.

```
streetViewPanorama.setPosition(new LatLng(25.1305784, 55.1170592));
```

but after I try to get Nearer PanoIds for that location then it always return null Value following is the code which i write:

```
StreetViewPanoramaLocation location = streetViewPanorama.getLocation();

Log.d("test","LocaTion:"+location);
if (location != null && location.links != null) {

       Log.d("test","size:"+location.links.length);

            streetViewPanorama.setPosition(location.links[0].panoId);
 }
```

please help me,Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

The location sometimes returns null value because it might have not been loaded. Just check if it exists. From [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23783819/android-streetview-check-if-there-is-any-view-for-given-location)

```
 @Override
 public void onStreetViewPanoramaReady(StreetViewPanorama streetViewPanorama) {
 mPanorama.setOnStreetViewPanoramaChangeListener(new StreetViewPanorama.OnStreetViewPanoramaChangeListener() {
      @Override
      public void onStreetViewPanoramaChange(StreetViewPanoramaLocation   streetViewPanoramaLocation) {
        if (streetViewPanoramaLocation != null && streetViewPanoramaLocation.links != null) {
            // location is present
        } else {
            // location not available
        }
    }
  });
```