# StreetViewPanorama().getLocation() inconsistent results?

Tags: android, google-maps

My intent is to show the fragment if there is something to show and hide it if there isn't.

My problem is that, given the same coordinates:

- On first attempt, `mStreetView.getStreetViewPanorama().getLocation()` has a non-null response and shows the view. However, the `Fragment` is black (blank).
- On second attempt, `mStreetView.getStreetViewPanorama().getLocation()` has a null response and the view stays hidden.

My code:

```
mStreetView.getView().setVisibility(View.GONE);
mStreetView.getStreetViewPanorama().setPosition(customMarker.getPosition());
if (mStreetView.getStreetViewPanorama().getLocation() != null && 
        mStreetView.getStreetViewPanorama().getLocation().links != null) {
    mStreetView.getView().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

I'm not sure how to go about debugging this. It seems to me that the results shouldn't vary like this, especially since, even though it has non-null results, the results have (apparently) no valid value to allow something to be displayed.

Edit:

This coordinate functions as expected and shows the view properly populated: 33.6645598,-111.9253126

This coordinate shows the view, but it is black, then later returns null: 33.6492448,-111.9354228

These results are consistent.

Edit2:

I attempted to use the `OnStreetViewPanoramaReadyCallback()`, however the results were the same.

Code is now:

```
mStreetView.getView().setVisibility(View.GONE);
mStreetView.getStreetViewPanoramaAsync(new OnStreetViewPanoramaReadyCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onStreetViewPanoramaReady(StreetViewPanorama streetViewPanorama) {
        streetViewPanorama.setPosition(customMarker.getPosition());
        if (streetViewPanorama.getLocation() != null && streetViewPanorama.getLocation().links != null) {
            mStreetView.getView().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In one of my old projects found there is a race condition if you try to access the location too early

what I did was setup a handler and have a post delayed runnable fire after 1000 milliseconds then check the location. Doing this provided consistent results.

I dont know if this is still the current behavior but you can read what I did here

[Android StreetView check if there is any view for given location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23783819/android-streetview-check-if-there-is-any-view-for-given-location/23785186#23785186)

**Edit**

there appears to be a `onStreetViewPanoramaReady` callback now, are you using that?

Comment: I'm not using `onStreetViewPanoramaReady`. I assumed that since I created the view much earlier in the program that I wouldn't have any race conditions. I also assumed that a race condition isn't the issue since in some locations, the functionality works as intended and will display the street view properly, but in others, it doesn't.

Comment: I attempted to use that callback, but it yielded no different results.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the ['getLocation()'](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/streetview#add_a_street_view_panorama) before the view has been created, it will return null. It is recommended to wait until view has been created. Also, you have to  [create a callback](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/OnStreetViewPanoramaReadyCallback) to let you know when the streetview is ready.

```
getStreetViewPanoramaAsync(new OnStreetViewPanoramaReadyCallback(){
@Override
public void onStreetViewPanoramaReady(StreetViewPanorama streetViewPanorama) {

}
})
```

Comment: I'm sorry to be rude, but please read my entire post. I've implemented that call already. It did not fix my problem.