# Are user uploaded Street Views available in the Google Maps Android API v2?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, google-street-view

Let's use [this location](https://www.google.com/maps/place/New+York,+NY/@39.9477959,-75.1850599,3a,75y,299.2h,88.65t/data=!3m8!1e1!3m6!1s-fGb70vjB5Uc%2FVEFDKCo_78I%2FAAAAAAAAKg4%2FkCDXqRM9qG8KUi5FBpzMpVD9hPBFwbFXw!2e4!3e11!6s%2F%2Flh4.googleusercontent.com%2F-fGb70vjB5Uc%2FVEFDKCo_78I%2FAAAAAAAAKg4%2FkCDXqRM9qG8KUi5FBpzMpVD9hPBFwbFXw%2Fw203-h101-n-k-no%2F!7i7778!8i3888!4m5!3m4!1s0x89c24fa5d33f083b:0xc80b8f06e177fe62!8m2!3d40.7127837!4d-74.0059413!6m1!1e1) as an example.  The lat/lng are 39.9477959/-75.1850599.

I can use the Google JS API to pull up this Street View no problem.  However, using these same coordinates and Google Maps Android API, all I get is a black screen.

To reproduce the issue clone and change the coordinates [here](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-samples/blob/master/ApiDemos/app/src/main/java/com/example/mapdemo/StreetViewPanoramaViewDemoActivity.java#L33).

Answer (score 0):

I think it will have no conflict if you are using the same coordinates. Based from this [related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23783819/android-streetview-check-if-there-is-any-view-for-given-location), black screen appears when location is not present. Just check whether it was loaded or not.

```
@Override
public void onStreetViewPanoramaReady(StreetViewPanorama streetViewPanorama) {
    mPanorama.setOnStreetViewPanoramaChangeListener(new StreetViewPanorama.OnStreetViewPanoramaChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onStreetViewPanoramaChange(StreetViewPanoramaLocation streetViewPanoramaLocation) {
            if (streetViewPanoramaLocation != null && streetViewPanoramaLocation.links != null) {
                // location is present
            } else {
                // location not available
            }
        }
    });
```

Here is an [example](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-samples/blob/master/ApiDemos/app/src/main/java/com/example/mapdemo/StreetViewPanoramaBasicDemoActivity.java) from [Google documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/streetview):

```
public class StreetViewPanoramaBasicDemoActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    // George St, Sydney
    private static final LatLng SYDNEY = new LatLng(-33.87365, 151.20689);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.street_view_panorama_basic_demo);

        SupportStreetViewPanoramaFragment streetViewPanoramaFragment =
                (SupportStreetViewPanoramaFragment)
                        getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.streetviewpanorama);
        streetViewPanoramaFragment.getStreetViewPanoramaAsync(
                new OnStreetViewPanoramaReadyCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onStreetViewPanoramaReady(StreetViewPanorama panorama) {
                        // Only set the panorama to SYDNEY on startup (when no panoramas have been
                        // loaded which is when the savedInstanceState is null).
                        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
                            panorama.setPosition(SYDNEY);
                        }
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: abielita, thanks, but the issue is that the user submitted location with lat/lng 39.9477959/-75.1850599 is available with the JS API but does not appear to be available in the Android API.  To reproduce the issue clone and change the coordinates to 39.9477959/-75.1850599 [here](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-samples/blob/master/ApiDemos/app/src/main/java/com/example/mapdemo/StreetViewPanoramaViewDemoActivity.java#L33).

Answer (score 0):

It seems not, see [Issue 7033](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=7033). There's a new, better workaround there.